# php read data from binary file

Tags: php, arrays, binary

i cant find the answer for my problem. i had the code

```
$arr = array(pack("d",1324),pack("d",151),pack("d",8564));
file_put_contents('C:\\Users\\Duc Nguyen\\Desktop\\text.bin', $arr);
```

so i got a binary file. i used the code

```
$s = file_get_contents('C:\\Users\\Duc Nguyen\\Desktop\\text.bin');
foreach(unpack("d", $s) as $n) 
    echo $n;
```

to read it but it didnt work.can you show me how i can read the data from the file. i prefer not to use the serialize/unserialize function.
thank you!

Comment: *didnt work* What does that mean? Your code works fine for me.

Comment: i mean it returns only the first number which is 1324

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just used the wrong format for [`pack()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php) and [`unpack()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php), just change `d` to `d*`. E.g:

```
$arr = array(pack("d*",1324),pack("d*",151),pack("d*",8564));
//...            v  ^               ^              ^
foreach(unpack("d*", $s) as $n)
```

And a quote from the manual:

> The repeater argument can be either an integer value **or * for repeating to the end of the input data.**

Comment: oh right. i should have read the manual carefully. thank you very much